# Python expression differnce

Tags: python

What is the difference between the expressions
***c = 299792458 and c = 2.99792458 * 10 ** 8*** in python?

is it same or different

Comment: did you see what they evaluate to? Do they have the same value and type?

Comment: If you had spent two seconds trying this code yourself, you would gave gotten an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

c = 299792458 this is an integer and 2.99792458 * 10 ** 8 will evaluate to a float. So to answer your question, no they are not the same.

```
type(299792458)
> <class 'int'>

type(2.99792458 * 10 ** 8) 
> <class 'float'>
```